# An unbiased dice is tossed seven times. Find the probability of getting a third six on the seventh throw.

Tags: probability, contest-math

Total sample space = $6^7$

Now in the first six throws, we need exactly two $6$. So number of ways to place two $6$ in the first six throws = $^6C_2$

Number of ways in which $6$ can come in the last throw = $1$

So shouldn't the probability of getting a third six on the seventh throw be = $\frac{^6C_2 \times1}{6^7}$

But it seems that I am wrong as this is not the correct answer provided. What case I am missing? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You need to get a $6$ on the seventh throw AND you need to have had exactly two $6's$ in the first six throws.

Comment: You forgot to account for the four non-six throws in the first six throws.

Comment: The probability you found of $\dfrac{\binom{6}{2}\times 1}{6^7}$ is the probability that not only you got your third six on the seventh throw, but that all other non-6 throws resulted very specifically in a $1$.  That is, you counted only sequences like 1661116 or 6111166 and so on but have not allowed for other sequences like 2661456 or 6221366 and so on

Comment: @angryavian : Ok! So then the number of ways to account for the four non-six throws in the first six throws will be $5^4$, right?

Comment: @Ganit That's right

Comment: I got the correct answer. I was missing the case of accounting for the four non-six throws in the first six throws. Thanks to all !